# wrapping text around circle in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-on-path

right now I have two separate type paths- I want type to wrap in continuous circle but still need the calico skies on top and sparkling company on bottom- basically want the type closer together so it appears to be constant circle. How do i extend the bottom circle shape to bring this type closer to top without changing the arc? 
[image]

Comment: I would think you need to add more letter spacing or spacing between the word and dot rather than changing the path.

Comment: Agree with AndrewH, I would keep them on separate paths. You could add space between letters or make the letters themselves wider, or a combination. You can find both options in the Type dialogue. (I'd show you but I'm on mobile atm)

Answer (score 1):

*The answer below is specific to the spacing issues demonstrated by the OP, [here is a more general tutorial if you are just getting started with typing along a path in Illustrator](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-type-on-a-path-in-illustrator--cms-20711).*

As mentioned above, it seems your paths are already positioned just fine and have the curve that you need. So, in order to position the text as you would like, you should worry about the letter spacing or tracking.

To amend this in Illustrator, you can use the **character panel**. This can usually be accessed by hitting CMD/CTRL + D for the keyboard shortcut. Alternatively, you can select where it says 'character' in the top navigation bar when you have the type tool (T) selected. (If both these methods were to fail you could always go to the Window Tab and select Type > Character).

This will toggle the box below that shows a range of tracking, leading and kerning options amongst other things.

[image: Character Panel Illustrator]

With your text selected, increase the tracking (second box on the right) to get more space between your letters. The character panel works just like this in both Photoshop and Indesign too!

Hope this helps!

P.S here's a [kerning game](http://type.method.ac/) if it was something you are interested in :)

Answer (score -1):

This answer needs a renewal.

Illustrator UI has changed dramatically since 2016.

[image]

Steps:

- Using Ellipse tool, draw a circle on artboard.
- Hold Shift key while dragging Ellipse to make a perfect circle.
- Select Type on a Path tool under T button on left toolbar.
- Click on the very edge of a circle.
- Start typing text.

Here's a [wrap text around circle](https://semicolon.dev/illustrator/how-to-type-text-around-circle-in-illustrator) tutorial for visuals.

Comment: The op has a circle, and wants to offset the text expressly not drawing a new circle. The UI has not changed since 2016 in any way and the answer is still the same to use character panel to adjust character position. either along path (tracking) or outwards inwards (baseline shifting). One can be of many oppinions on the answer but it atleast adresses the question this does not. Please fix.